# PDF to image c# / emgu.cv

Tags: opencv, pdf, render, bmp, emgucv

Сейчас в проекте используется nreco pdfRenderer для того что бы конвертировать pdf страницы в .bmp изображения. производительности в паре с emgu.cv стало не хватать. какие есть доступные. а главное быстрые альтернативы? в плане emgu.cv думал переход на opencv(c++), может, есть еще варианты? или комплексный ocr какой-нибудь окажется быстрым.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: pdf векторный или растровый? Если растровый, то нужно не рендерить картинку, а извлекать. Это и быстрее и правильнее.